# How to use enum in switch vs integer using

Tags: c, enums, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I have `enum` in header file.

```
typedef enum{
     up = 8, down = 2, left = 4, right = 6
}direction;
```

I want use enum to identify type of move.
Like this:

```
void sayTypeOfMove(int type){

     switch(type){
          case direction.up:
                 printf("IT IS UP MOVE...");
                 break;
     }

}
```

The code does not compile , where is the problem?

Comment: `direction.up`.....:-) it's not a structure member, after all...

Comment: Even for a simple question like this, where the problem is obvious considering the code, you should always provide the actual (complete and unedited) errors you get when posting a question regarding build errors.

Comment: As for your problem, I think that looking for a nice book or tutorial might be a good idea.

Comment: Before you ask your next question, you probably mean `'2', '4', '6' and '8'` not `2,4,6, and 8` for your direction_t enums, assuming you are using a numeric keypad and getchar() or equivalent ... otherwise use `switch(direction-'0'){` ... sorry I just can't bring myself use type as a variable name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C understands the enum elements when it knows you're dealing with that enum, so the right code would be

```
void sayTypeOfMove(direction type){

     switch(type){
          case up:
                 printf("IT IS UP MOVE...");
                 break;
     }

}
```

By the way, `type` is a really bad name, because it feels so much like it should be a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

With a definition like

```
typedef enum{
     up = 8, down = 2, left = 4, right = 6
}direction;
```

`direction` is a *type*, it's not a variable.

You need to define a variable of that type, and then use the value.

And remember, the enum does not have a *member variable* access concept, at all. The enumerator list contains *"enumeration-constant"* s. You can just use them directly, as a value.